# @Scheduled не запускается

Tags: java, spring-boot

у меня не запускается @Scheduled. Через дебаггер не удается узнать причину, может кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой?! Заранее спасибо!

```
@Component
@AutoConfiguration
public class ScheduledTasks {

    static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class.getName());

    private final CompanyService companyService;

    private final StatisticsService statisticsService;

    public ScheduledTasks(CompanyService companyService, StatisticsService statisticsService) {
        this.companyService = companyService;
        this.statisticsService = statisticsService;
    }


    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 1000)
    public void getSymbol() {

        LOGGER.info("INFO: Getting information ");
        companyService.save();

    }

    @Scheduled(initialDelay=5000, cron = "${interval-in-cron}")
    public void getStatistics() {
        statisticsService.save();

    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${interval-in-out}")
    public void outputExpensiveStocks() {
        LOGGER.info("INFO: Expensive stocks ");
        statisticsService.getExpensiveStocks();
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${interval-in-out}")
    public void outputChangedPrices() {
        LOGGER.info("INFO: Changed prices");
        statisticsService.getChangedPrices();
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
interval-in-cron = 0 5 * * * *
interval-in-out = 5 0 * * * *
```

**Main class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class RestapiStatisticsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestapiStatisticsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключалась в том что **initialDelay** не работает вместе с **cron**

Comment: У меня все работает.